# Morphism of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

So I have an exercise that I'm not sure what is being asked to accomplish.
It states:

If $f:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ is a morphism of rings with unity (i.e. a morphism of rings such that $f(1)=1$), then $f$ is the identity.

This seems to me to be more of a statement than a question.
I'm new to abstract algebra so what the goal here might be obvious for more experienced mathematicians despite the badly worded problem.
If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It means that you are supposed to prove that statement

Comment: This is just apllying the definition and noting that $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ is equal to $x$ times $1$. Do you see how to use this?

Comment: This reminds me. I was once asked to help resolve a dispute about a problem in an exam that didn't actually ask the students to do anything, so some of them did nothing. Of course they were expected to prove the assertion in the question, but in the end we decided we had to give them the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $f(n)=f(n.1)=f(1+...+1)$ Where $1+....1$ represents the addition of $1$ $n$-times, you deduce that $f(1)=nf(1)$ since $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ so $f(n)=n$.